# Pygame timers and how to change to seconds

Tags: pygame

i am using pygame timers to make print hello once every second without pauseing other lines of code

How can i change milli second to seconds on pygame timer

Comment: Multiplicate your milliseconds with 1000?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like what you're really looking for is `pygame.time.set_timer(eventid, milliseconds)`. This will insert an event with the specified id into the queue every amount of milliseconds specified. So for example:

```
pygame.time.set_timer(pygame.USEREVENT + 1, 1000)

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.USEREVENT + 1:
            print("Hello")
    # Your other game loop code...
```

will print "hello" every second (you can change it to print to the screen, of course) and won't prevent you from executing other code.